# Highlight PDF based on Excel Values

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, pdf, pdf-generation

I have an excel sheet, with 2 cols, col A has labels and col B has values for these labels, some of these values are below 1 and some are above 1, and I have a pdf file with the same labels of col A, i needed a  vba code to highlight the values above 1 in the pdf file based on col B in the excel sheet.
I developed the following code with many trials, but it always gave error 438 in the following line of code "Set search = pdf.FindText(label, 0, 0, False, False)"

Code:

```
Sub HighlightPDF()

Dim xls As Workbook  
Dim pdf As Object 
Dim excelLabels As Range  
Dim pdfPage  As Object 
Dim words As Object 
Dim i As Integer                

'Open Excel workbook and get sheet
Set xls = Workbooks.Open("D:\Softwares\A.Y\Highlight PDF VBA\HighlightPDF2.xlsm")
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = xls.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Get range of labels in Excel
Set excelLabels = sheet.Range("A1:A" & sheet.Cells(sheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

'Open PDF and get page
Set pdf = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
pdf.Open "D:\Softwares\A.Y\Highlight PDF VBA\HighlightPDF.pdf"
Set pdfPage = pdf.AcquirePage(0) 'Get the first page of the PDF document

'Loop through labels in Excel and PDF
For i = 1 To excelLabels.Count
    'If value in Excel is > 1, highlight PDF word
    If sheet.Range("B" & i).Value > 1 Then
        Dim label As String
        label = sheet.Range("A" & i).Value 'Get the label text
        Set words = CreateObject("AcroExch.HiliteList") 'Create a new highlight list
        Dim search As Object
        Set search = pdf.FindText(label, 0, 0, False, False) 'Search for the label text on the page
        While Not search.IsNull
            words.Add search.GetText, search.GetQuads 'Add the search result to the highlight list
            search = pdf.FindText(label, 0, search) 'Find the next occurrence
        Wend
        If words.count > 0 Then 'Check if any words were highlighted
            pdfPage.AddHighlights words 'Add the highlights to the page
        End If
    End If
Next

xls.Close
pdf.Close
End Sub
```

i tried also the following 2nd scenario, but the saved pdf file doesn't show any highlights and i can't figure out the reason, please help

```
Sub HighlightPDFValuesAndSave()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pdfFilePath As String
    Dim objAcroApp As Object
    Dim objAcroAVDoc As Object
    Dim objAcroPDDoc As Object
    Dim objAcroPage As Object
    Dim objAcroRect As Object
    Dim i As Long
    
 
    pdfFilePath = "D:\Softwares\A.Y\Highlight PDF VBA\HighlightPDF.pdf"
    
     Set objAcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set objAcroAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
    If objAcroAVDoc.Open(pdfFilePath, "") Then
        Set objAcroPDDoc = objAcroAVDoc.GetPDDoc()
    End If
    

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 
    
    ' Loop through each row in column B
    For i = 1 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        ' Check if the value in column B is greater than 1
        If ws.Cells(i, "B").value > 1 Then
            ' Search for the value in the PDF file
            Debug.Print "Searching for value: " & ws.Cells(i, "B").value
            Set objAcroPage = Nothing
            Set objAcroRect = Nothing
            Set objAcroPage = objAcroPDDoc.AcquirePage(i - 1)
            If Not objAcroPage Is Nothing Then
                Set objAcroRect = objAcroPage.AddNewAnnot(-1, "Square", Array(0, 0, 1, 1))
                objAcroRect.FillColor = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Change to red color
                               objAcroRect.Locked = True
                objAcroRect.SetRect 0, 0, 100, 100 
                Debug.Print "Value highlighted on page " & objAcroPage.pageNumber
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Save the PDF file
    objAcroPDDoc.Save PDSaveFull, pdfFilePath
    

    objAcroAVDoc.Close True
    objAcroApp.Exit
    
    
    MsgBox "PDF highlighting and saving complete."
End Sub
```

I tried to fix many lines of code, and I have the Adobe Acrobat library installed. However, I am still encountering the same problem, and the code is not working. Therefore, please provide an updated working code, or if there is another way to get this to work. Thanks..